# Moving existing Solr to new machine

Tags: solr, solr5

G'Day.  Apologies in advance, I have never seen or heard of Solr until a few weeks ago!
I am writing a new system.  To be able to do so I need to run the old system in a VM so I can see the fine points of the application functionality.

I have the database running, easy.  I have Solr 5.5.4 installed and running.  I know that is old but I was informed that the application relies on that vintage of Solr.  I created a core name 'collation1' as instructed and the Solr management page sees it OK.

I was given two files,

```
schema.xml
solrconfig.xml
```

Looking at the schema it describes stuff in the application database so I dig what it is doing.  I read all of the 5.5 documentation and googled and googled, and I can't find out what to do with these files!  The 5.5 PDF doco dropped a hint that these files SHOULD live in

```
/var/solr/data/collation1/conf
```

however, if I copy the files there I get a big ugly bright red ERROR LOADING .... screen and it appears VERY broken.

Anyone have a hint for me?

Cheers,
MArk.

Comment: Exactly what the problem is depends on what the error message is. It's impossible to say otherwise.

Comment: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core collation1: org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceNotFoundException: Can't find resource 'mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt' in classpath or '/var/solr/data/collation1'

That means nothing to me!

Answer (score 1):

There's a reference somewhere in your schema to `mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt`. This file does not exist, which means that the schema is unable to load - since it doesn't know what to do when you're depending on a file that doesn't exist.

Either remove the field type using `mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt`, find the appropriate file (if you need the functionality) or create an empty file named the same.